# Unexpected Progress Bar after login

Tags: macos, high-sierra, filevault

I just install macOS 10.13 High Sierra and after entering my password to login a progress bar starts running.

What's different is the background turns black and shows only a stark progress bar running.

[image: Loading bar]

I search on internet and some said it's about fileValt but i don't want that. I try with turn off fileValt this bar not show up and take less time to boot up. may be i'll try with re-install should be fixed this.

Is this something I can avoid or fix?

Answer (score 1):

That is the boot process happening (or perhaps stuck and not happening ) between the file vault unlock screen and the full macOS being booted. If you powered off the machine during the last reboot, this full disk check could take a long time if you don’t have problems. If you do have problems, it might freeze or never finish.

This isn’t much different than the Sierra process, so the way to diagnose is the same.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201573

If you start up in verbose mode, you can see if it stops in a specific spot.

- https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25421